# Unknown size error

Tags: c

I have to use this code but I get receive the following error:

> error c2036'Complex_Z 'unknown size

```
typedef struct Complex_Z{ 
 double r, i; 
} ;

void update_projection_zprimme(struct Complex_Z *X, struct Complex_Z *Y, struct Complex_Z *Z, 
   int numCols, int maxCols, int blockSize, struct Complex_Z *rwork, 
   struct primme_params *primme) {

   int j;    /* Loop variable  */ 
   int count;
  struct Complex_Z tpone = {+1.0e+00,+0.0e00};
  struct Complex_Z  tzero = {+0.0e+00,+0.0e00};

   /* --------------------------------------------------------------------- */
   /* Zero the work array to prevent floating point traps during all-reduce */
   /* --------------------------------------------------------------------- */

   for (j = 0; j < maxCols*blockSize; j++) {
      rwork[j] = tzero; //error c2036'Complex_Z 'unknown size
   }
```

Comment: Please make the question subject a real question, and format your code so that it can be read.

Comment: why are people burying this so quickly? Give the newbies a break. There is some code and a problem.

Comment: @z5h, Agreed. There was nothing here that couldn't have been fixed in less than a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
typedef struct Complex_Z{ 
    double r, i; 
} ;
```

coincidentally declares the type `struct Complex_Z`, but doesn't give a name for the `typedef`.  Specifically, it does not make `Complex_Z` into a synonym of `struct Complex_Z`.

However, I don't see where the code is referring to just `Complex_Z` - though the reported error message indicates that it probably was missing the `struct`.  Since the code is a fragment, I think there was a change between the time the compiler ran and the code was displayed to us.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that these pieces of code come from more than one source file, and your for loop occurs in a location where the definition of Complex_Z is not visible.

Comment: now i know the reason of the error i have this Warning  warning C4627: '#include "complex .h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use so it can not see the header file in the source code any help in this warning

Comment: @basma: Move the `#include "stdafx.h"` line so it is the first of the `#include` lines.

Comment: So, I have the most correct answer here (without knowing the particular environment, and specifics of precompiled headers), yet I get downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Because you declare `typedef struct Complex_Z {}` which is invalid 'C'

it s/b:

```
typedef struct  {
double r, i;
} Complex_Z;
```

and then reference `struct Complex_Z`

when you should be referencing `Complex_Z`

for example:

```
  struct Complex_Z tpone = {+1.0e+00,+0.0e00};
  struct Complex_Z  tzero = {+0.0e+00,+0.0e00};
```

s/b

```
  Complex_Z tpone = {+1.0e+00,+0.0e00};
  Complex_Z  tzero = {+0.0e+00,+0.0e00};
```

Comment: This is not C++ (but your comments are accurate for C++, and inaccurate for C).